# How to use the created CNN model with new data in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I just followed a tutorial that classifies 10k images of cats and dogs with CNN with Keras(Tensorflow backend).

Everything seems OK, I obtained good accuracy on both test and training sets:

```
....    
    Epoch 24/25
    250/250 [==============================] - 26s 104ms/step - loss: 0.2938 - acc: 0.8745 - val_loss: 0.4235 - val_acc: 0.8270
    Epoch 25/25
    250/250 [==============================] - 25s 99ms/step - loss: 0.2901 - acc: 0.8719 - val_loss: 0.4324 - val_acc: 0.8270
```

**But how do I use this model to predict the class of a new image?**

My code that creates and fits the classifier:

```
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
import PIL
#these 2 lines are for timer
import cv2
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()
# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(64, 64, 3)))
# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())
# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation="relu"))
classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"))
# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 250,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 63)
# elapsed time
end = timer()
print(end - start)
# end of work message
import os
os.system('say "your program has finished"')
```

Dataset: [here](http://www.superdatascience.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Convolutional-Neural-Networks.zip)

Comment: Did you check the predict method? https://keras.io/models/sequential/#predict

Comment: yes but I could not implement the code to my case.In other words, I couldnt realize how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. I like to use `skimage`, but that's up to you.

```
import skimage.io as io
import skimage.transform as tr

img = io.imread('img.jpg')         # Reads the image
img = tr.resize(img, (64, 64, 3))  # Resizes the image
img = img[np.newaxis, ...]         # Adds a new dim to simulate a batch
pred = classifier.predict(img)     # Predicts a value between 0 and 1

if pred > 0.5:
    print('Class 1')
else:
    print('Class 2')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for. 

Could you describe why you resized the image as (64,64) since the colored image has three dimensions?

Comment: That's a fair point. In skimage it's optional to provide the number of channels, but since your model is expecting 3, you're safer off adding it. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: one further question, how do I get the confidence of each prediction?

a non-cat&dog image will also be predicted as one of them. I want to prevent it.

Comment: Skipping my If-Else, you could look at the actual predicted value and the closer it is to 0.5 the less confident the model is. If you want more insight about the confidence for each class, consider setting ```class_mode``` to ```categorical```. That way your output won't be a single value, but an array with the length of 2 (number of classes). I prefer this even for binary classifiers, because it's a little simpler to extend my code for more than two classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create another `ImageDataGenerator()` for the data that you'll be predicting on. Note, this data you plan to predict on is technically called the *test set*, whereas the data that you've called *test set* is actually the *validation set*.

In any case, after creating an `ImageDataGenerator()` for the test set, you can call `classifier.predict_generator()` in a similar fashion as to where you call `classifier.fit_generator()`. I show an example of how to do this [here](https://youtu.be/HDom7mAxCdc).